# Are all finite morphism etale after restriction.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a finite morphism between irreducible varieties $f: X \rightarrow Y$. Is it true that there is a Zariski open of $Y$ like $U$, such that after base changing $f$ along $U\hookrightarrow Y$ it becomes finite etale?

Restricting $f$ to its smooth locus $V\subset X$ is going to be etale but it won't be finite. So if $f$ was flat it would have been an open morphism then $f(V)$ would have been open and base change along $f(V)\hookrightarrow Y$ would have worked. But $f$ is not flat.

Comment: You're basically asking for your morphism to be generically flat (easy, see Grothendieck) and generically unramified (depends on characteristic). I think you should be able to make a pretty good start from those two hints.